# Different result from sizeof() from [] and .data()

Tags: c++

```
const GLfloat tmpArray[] = { 
  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};
std::cerr << sizeof(tmpArray) << std::endl;
```

This gives a result of 36

```
std::vector<GLfloat> tmpVector { 
  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};
std::cerr << sizeof(tmpVector.data()) << std::endl;
```

While this gives a result of 8. I read here on SO that you can get an array out of a vector using the .data() function. But why does it yeild different results? How would I go about to make these sizes match?

Comment: Remember that `sizeof()` is a compile time constant. Here you are getting the size of a pointer: `sizeof(tmp.data())`

Comment: But wouldn't sizeof for the array give the size of the first pointer in the array? What makes them different?

Comment: No it would not. The `sizeof()` the static array is known at compile time. The vector data() function returns a pointer. The key is what @derhass just mentioned. A static array is not a pointer.

Comment: arrays aren't pointers

Comment: Thank you, think I have to read a bit more about arrays and keep to them when I develop using OpenGL, as it is using sizeof quite a bit on these kinds of things.

Comment: Just a follow-up, there is no way to make these sizes match? There is no way to extract a "real" array out of a vector that has the computed size at compiletime?

Comment: The problem is a vector is a dynamically sized container that changes size at runtime. An array is sized at compile time and can not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I go about to make these sizes match?

Consider using (tmpVector.size() * sizeof(FLfloat)) ...

```
     const GLfloat tmpArray[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     };
     cerr << "\n  sizeof(tmpArray) :                    "
          << sizeof(tmpArray) << endl;

     vector<GLfloat> tmpVector {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     };
     cerr << "\n  sizeof(tmpVector.data())               "
          << sizeof(tmpVector.data()) << endl;

     cerr << "\n  tmpVector.size() * sizeof(GLfloat) :  "
          << tmpVector.size() * sizeof(GLfloat) << endl;
```

With output:

```
sizeof(tmpArray) :                    36

sizeof(tmpVector.data())               8

tmpVector.size() * sizeof(GLfloat) :  36
```

The vector elements are stored contiguously, just like the array elements.

Comment: Note:  On my Lubuntu 18.04 64 bit desktop, with g++ v7.3:  (a) with tmpVector.size() == 0 (i.e. empty), sizeof (tmpVector) reports 24 bytes, regardless of element type   (b) with tmpVector.size() reporting 1000 elements, sizeof(tmpVector) reports 24 (bytes),.  The std::vector<T> automatic memory (~stack) object is 24 bytes of items used to manage the data contents in the heap.  While your array of 9 x 4 byte floats occupies 36 bytes of automatic memory, tmpStack occupies only 24 bytes of automatic (~stack) memory, and the 36 bytes are in the much bigger (~4Gbytes) heap .

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(tmpArray)` returns the size of the array as expected.

`sizeof(tmpVector.data())` returns the size of what is returned by the `data()` method, which is a pointer (`GLfloat*`). On your 64bit platform, the size of a pointer is 8 bytes.